# Sinatra with Puma gives twice the output in the terminal

Tags: logging, sinatra, puma, rackup

I have added Puma to my sinatra app, and now I get two lines of output for requests in the terminal. I've checked and it isn't actually calling the code twice, and I'm guessing that maybe Puma is outputting the request information along with Sinatra.

As a demonstration, I've created a simple app as follows:

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.0'

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'puma'
```

**config.ru**

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  'Hello World'
end

run Sinatra::Application
```

Here is the command I run:

```
rackup -s puma
```

and here's the type of output I receive when I browse http://localhost:9292/

```
R5001755:test louis.sayers$ rackup -s puma
Puma 2.11.3 starting...
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:9292
::1 - - [03/Jul/2015:21:46:37 +1000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11 0.0074
::1 - - [03/Jul/2015:21:46:37 +1000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11 0.0222
```

I've uploaded the [example project to github](https://github.com/LouisSayers/puma-sinatra-logging) if you'd like to have a play

Any ideas as to what's going on? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is caused by the [`CommonLogger` middleware](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.6.4/lib/rack/commonlogger.rb). It is added by both [Rack (when using `rackup`)](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb#L214) and by [Sinatra (when logging is enabled)](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1744), resulting in the duplicated output. Sinatra actually uses a [custom subclass of this middleware](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/v1.4.6/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L207-L221) to try and address this issue. In order for it to work it patches the original `CommonLogger` class.

The issue arises because Puma also [defines its own version of `CommonLogger`](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/v2.11.3/lib/puma/rack_patch.rb#L8) which doesn’t include the changes introduced by Sinatra. When Puma is loaded after Sinatra the Puma version overwrites the patched version, and so the original behaviour (duplicated output lines) occurs.

There are a few ways to workaround this issue. You could disable logging in Sinatra to prevent the duplicate middleware from being added. The Sinatra logging setting applies to both the `CommonLogger` and the [`Logger`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.6.4/lib/rack/logger.rb) middleware (which is what the [`logger` helper](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Logging) uses), so you might want to add the `Logger` middleware yourself:

```
disable :logging
use Rack::Logger
```

You could also prevent `rackup` from adding the `CommonLogger` middleware by using the `-q` option to the `rackup` command:

```
$ rackup -q -s puma
```

Another option would be to ensure that Puma is loaded before Sinatra, so that when Sinatra patches `CommonLogger` it is patching the Puma version and the patch isn’t overwritten later. You can do this by using the `-r` option to `rackup` to force it to load Puma:

```
$ rackup -s puma -r puma
```

Comment: Wow, that's truly an incredible answer. Great explanation, and extremely helpful! Thanks a lot!!